# Collection <CALayerArray: 0x1cdb9b90> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, ios

i realise this has been asked many times, but i just don't know where the fault lies in my code, sorry for being dumb.

I do know the fault is from this method:

```
-(void)getDataFromDatabase {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    indicator.center = self.view.center;
    [indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
    [indicator startAnimating];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height)];

    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.view addSubview:overlay];
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];

    NSString *listingurl;

    listingurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.herefordshire-tourism-guide.co.uk/app/query.php?getlisting=1&listingname=%@", rowSelectedName];

    listingurl = [listingurl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:listingurl];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSStringEncoding encoding;

    NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                             error:&error];

    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];

    // In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
    NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
    if (dict)
    {
        rows = dict[@"listings"];
    }
    dict = rows[0];

    self.photos.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:18.0];
    self.likes.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:18.0];
    self.businessName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Extrabld" size:20.0];
    self.address.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:16.0];

    self.navigationItem.title = dict[@"business"];

    NSString *favdb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dict[@"favs"]];

    if ([favdb isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *fav = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 Likes"];
        self.favourites.text = fav;
    } else {
        NSString *fav = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Likes", dict[@"favs"]];
        self.favourites.text = fav;
    }

    if ([favdb isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSString *fav = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1 Like"];
        self.favourites.text = fav;
    }

    self.businessName.text = dict[@"business"];
    self.address.text = dict[@"location"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        indicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 85, 40.0, 40.0);
        [indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:indicator];

        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict[@"image1"]]]];

        self.image.image = img;

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
        [indicator stopAnimating];
    });

    listingLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[dict[@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude:[dict[@"lon"] doubleValue]];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    float kilometers = [appDelegate.currentLoc distanceFromLocation:listingLoc] / 1000;

    int milesint = kilometers * 0.621371192;

    NSString *milesOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i miles", milesint];

    self.distance.text = milesOut;

    networkImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (dict[@"image1"] != @"") {
        [networkImages addObject:dict[@"image1"]];
    }

    [indicator stopAnimating];
    [overlay removeFromSuperview];
}
```

and im calling that method in the viewWillAppear method...

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getDataFromDatabase) withObject:nil];`

Any tips, my code may be a bit shoddy, any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of code.Where do you iterate through the array elements?

Comment: Well, anytime that you interact with UIKit methods (like adding and removing subviews above) it must be done on the main thread, and not in a background thread like you are doing here.  UIKit is **not** thread-safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got several problems in here, mostly related to modifying the UI on a background thread, which you must never do. For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 85, 40.0, 40.0);
    [indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    ...
```

Here you're modifying the current view's list of subviews on a background thread. That's not legal. Most UIKit methods have to run on the main thread (from a GCD point of view, this is the main queue).

This line is also extremely dangerous inside of `viewWillAppear:` (or most anywhere):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getDataFromDatabase) withObject:nil];
```

Your view could appear and disappear multiple times during `getDataFromDatabase` (side note: you should call this `fetchDataFromDatabase`. "get" has a special meaning in Cocoa). If the view appears multiple times, you can wind up with many threads running simultaneously, which is certainly not what you meant.

You should almost never use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`. Use `NSOperationQueue` or dispatch queues to manage background operations.

Comment: I have just started learning, so complicated! Can you give me some code examples so i can have a play with it!

Comment: Haven't got a clue where to start!

Comment: I would start simpler. I don't see anything in the above code that needs a background thread. You can do a lot of iOS development without spawning threads. Your primary problem is that you've integrated a JSON network fetch into a view controller. Don't do that. Put your data fetches into a model class that just manages data (and use NSURLConnection to fetch the data asynchronously). Then the view controller will respond to changes in the model classes. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Look closely at how `UITableView` works. Note that it just displays data that is provided from somewhere else. Most of your program should work this way. You have some set of objects (Model) that keep track of all the data, talk to the network to fetch it, etc. Then you have views that display the current state of that data. And View Controllers just glue the two together.

Comment: Okay,have you got Skype, so i can have a chat with you a bit more in depth?

Comment: My contact information is on my profile. I provide a consulting services and would be happy to discuss my rates over email. You may want to start with Stanford's free course, however. https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/ipad-iphone-app-development/id495052415 And I also highly recommend the accompanying free iBook from Daniel Steinberg. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/ipad-iphone-app-development/id571023793?mt=13